# PHP HTMLPurifier Not Removing Empty Table (but does on 'Live Demo'..)

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

Working with HTMLPurifier on my localhost with an html string.

Here's my code:

```
require_once '/htmlpurifier-4.9.2/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$html = '<table class="product-description-table">
         <tbody>
         <tr>
         <td class="item" colspan="3">Test Title</td>
         </tr>
         <p class="MsoNormal c2"><strong>Test Paragraph 3</strong></p>
         <p class="MsoNormal c2"><strong>Test Paragraph 2</strong></p>
         <p class="MsoNormal c2"><strong>Test Paragraph 3</strong></p>
         <p class="c5"></p>
         <p class="MsoNormal c2"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
         <strong class="c6"><strong><em><br></em></strong></strong>
         <p class="c2"></p>
         <p class="c4"></p>
         </td>
         <td class="product-content-border"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td class="gallery" colspan="3">
         <table>
         <tbody>
         <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
         </table>
         </td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
         </table>';

         $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
         $config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty', true);
         $config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes', true);
         $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
         $clean_html = $purifier->purify($html);

         echo $clean_html;
```

Now, with the exact same string, and (assumingly) the exact same filters `AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty` and `AutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes` works fine on the [Live Demo](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5BAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.Linkify%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.Predicate%5D=&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5D=1&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5D=1&filter%5BNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5D=1&filter%5BCore.CollectErrors%5D=0&filter%5BNull_HTML.Allowed%5D=1&filter%5BNull_HTML.Doctype%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.SafeObject%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.TidyLevel%5D=medium&filter%5BURI.DisableExternalResources%5D=0&filter%5BNull_URI.Munge%5D=1&html=%3Ctable+class%3D%22product-description-table%22%3E%0D%0A%3Ctbody%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd+class%3D%22item%22+colspan%3D%223%22%3ETest+Title%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22MsoNormal+c2%22%3E%3Cstrong%3ETest+Paragraph+3%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22MsoNormal+c2%22%3E%3Cstrong%3ETest+Paragraph+2%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22MsoNormal+c2%22%3E%3Cstrong%3ETest+Paragraph+3%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22c5%22%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22MsoNormal+c2%22%3E%3Cstrong%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cstrong+class%3D%22c6%22%3E%3Cstrong%3E%3Cem%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fem%3E%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22c2%22%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22c4%22%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd+class%3D%22product-content-border%22%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd+class%3D%22gallery%22+colspan%3D%223%22%3E%0D%0A%3Ctable%3E%0D%0A%3Ctbody%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftable%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftable%3E&submit=Submit)

Output:

```
<table class="product-description-table"><tbody><tr><td class="item" colspan="3">Test Title</td>
</tr></tbody></table><p class="MsoNormal c2"><strong>Test Paragraph 3</strong></p>
<p class="MsoNormal c2"><strong>Test Paragraph 2</strong></p>
<p class="MsoNormal c2"><strong>Test Paragraph 3</strong></p>

<p class="MsoNormal c2"><strong> </strong></p>
<strong class="c6"><strong><em><br /></em></strong></strong>
```

But with my PHP code, when I view source, it is keeping the empty table.

Output:

```
<table class="product-description-table"><tbody><tr><td class="item" colspan="3">Test Title</td>
</tr></tbody></table><p class="MsoNormal c2"><strong>Test Paragraph 3</strong></p>
<p class="MsoNormal c2"><strong>Test Paragraph 2</strong></p>
<p class="MsoNormal c2"><strong>Test Paragraph 3</strong></p>

<p class="MsoNormal c2"><strong> </strong></p>
<strong class="c6"><strong><em><br /></em></strong></strong>
<table><tbody><tr><td></td>
<td></td>
</tr><tr><td></td>
<td></td>
</tr><tr><td></td>
<td></td>
</tr><tr><td></td>
<td></td>
</tr><tr><td></td>
<td></td>
</tr><tr><td></td>
<td></td>
</tr><tr><td></td>
<td></td>
</tr><tr><td></td>
<td></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

Why is this not working? How is my PHP script not getting the same output as the [Live Demo](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5BAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.Linkify%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.Predicate%5D=&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5D=1&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5D=1&filter%5BNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5D=1&filter%5BCore.CollectErrors%5D=0&filter%5BNull_HTML.Allowed%5D=1&filter%5BNull_HTML.Doctype%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.SafeObject%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.TidyLevel%5D=medium&filter%5BURI.DisableExternalResources%5D=0&filter%5BNull_URI.Munge%5D=1&html=%3Ctable+class%3D%22product-description-table%22%3E%0D%0A%3Ctbody%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd+class%3D%22item%22+colspan%3D%223%22%3ETest+Title%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22MsoNormal+c2%22%3E%3Cstrong%3ETest+Paragraph+3%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22MsoNormal+c2%22%3E%3Cstrong%3ETest+Paragraph+2%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22MsoNormal+c2%22%3E%3Cstrong%3ETest+Paragraph+3%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22c5%22%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22MsoNormal+c2%22%3E%3Cstrong%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cstrong+class%3D%22c6%22%3E%3Cstrong%3E%3Cem%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fem%3E%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22c2%22%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp+class%3D%22c4%22%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd+class%3D%22product-content-border%22%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd+class%3D%22gallery%22+colspan%3D%223%22%3E%0D%0A%3Ctable%3E%0D%0A%3Ctbody%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftable%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftable%3E&submit=Submit)?

Comment: I don't see the live demo using an invalid html as you

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  In the Live Demo the `HTML Purifier Input (get)` section has the exact same block of html in my php script for the variable `$html`.. just double checked

Comment: I think the Live Demo link is working. But if not you can always go to http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php and just paste in my `$html` contents

Comment: Let me be more specific: `</tr><p class="MsoNormal c2"><strong>Test Paragraph 3</strong></p>` why are you putting `p` element directly inside a `tbody` and not inside a `td` element? That's what's invalid - In that case the browser will close the `table` and all its descending open tags. This make the output of htmlpurifier unpredictable

Comment: I'm not putting anything anywhere. These are html blocks that were given to me.  They are a complete mess, I know.  Hence me trying things like HTMLPurifier, Tidy and other things to try and clean them up.  Anyways I know they are invalid I'm just wondering why I'm getting different outputs.  In my PHP script I want that empty table removed like the demo outputs...

Comment: Maybe you have `&nbsp;` there? Try adding `$config->set( 'AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp', true );`

Comment: Nope, added it and it's the exact same output with empty table and all.  I'm wondering if this is a bug, or something. I don't understand it.  Maybe I'll try an earlier version or something...

Comment: I'm thinking this might be a bug.  I submitted a support thread on their forum.  I did find a solution for this.  I went back into the version history one by one and the most recent version that removed the table was `htmlpurifier-4.5.0` ... `htmlpurifier-4.6.0` and higher kept the code in my script.  So I guess I'm just going to use this earlier version for now.

Comment: Thank you for the update. You can self-answer your question to let other users with similar issue to know about it

Comment: Just found an answer from their support forum.  Tested and worked, posted the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it worked out with HTML Purifier Support.. all I had to do was add this to my `$config`

```
$config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.Predicate', [
    'table' =>
        []
]);
```

and it's working with version `4.9.2`. the pesky table is gone.